# joining or merging json objects after underscore groupBy

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I use underscore.js in my current project which has a nice `_.groupBy` method.

this groups my array's in such a format.

```
var obj1 ={
  '0':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...}],
  '1':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...}],
  '2':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...}]
}

var obj2 = {
  '0':[{ ... another json object...},{ ...another json object...}],
  '1':[{ ... another json object...},{ ...another json object...}],
  '2':[{ ... another json object...},{ ... another json object...}]
}
```

now I want to join/merge/extend them... but `_.extend` does not work as I would expect it.

My expected result would be

```
{'0':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... another json object...},{ ...another json object...}],
'1':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... another json object...},{ ...another json object...}],
 '2':[{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... json object...},{ ... another json object...},{ ... another json object...}]}
```

basically I need to extend the array based on the json key of `obj1` and `obj2` even if the inner json objects are different.

Would basically need something like a sql join operation for json objects...

So any help would be great...

Comment: Those aren't JSON objects. They're just objects. :-) JSON is a textual data notation (it's a subset of what you're using there, which is JavaScript object initializer syntax). (And those examples are perfectly valid object initializers, but wouldn't be valid JSON, which requires keys and strings be in double quotes, not single quotes.) Sorry not to be able to help with the actual problem, I don't know underscore.js at all, so I don't know if it has something to help you with this. JavaScript itself doesn't, you just have to loop through and do the array appending yourself.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the heads up. This is what comes out of the underscore groupBy ... does this effect anything on the _.extend method. Or did you mentioned it for the correctness of the wording. Thanks for the reply =)

Comment: @ silverfighter: Just to correct the terminology, because sometimes it matters. Sorry not to be of any help with underscore.js, I don't know it. (I added a bit to the comment above if you didn't see it.) Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as no underscore.js-specific answer has appeared, here's a general JavaScript one:

To merge `obj2` into `obj1`, loop through `obj2`'s entries and append those arrays to the equivalent arrays on `obj1`, like this:

```
var key, a1, a2;
for (key in obj2) {
  if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    a2 = obj2[key];
    a1 = obj1[key];
    if (a1) {
      a1.push.apply(a1, a2); // Tricky, see below
    }
    else {
      obj1[key] = a2;
    }
  }
}
```

That merges `obj2` into `obj1`, modifying `obj1`'s arrays in place. It reuses `obj2`'s arrays if `obj1` doesn't have one in the corresponding slot.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ujeyuv/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ujeyuv/1/edit)

About that "tricky" bit:

```
a1.push.apply(a1, a2);
```

What that does is *append* the elements from `a2` to the end of `a1`. [Details on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/05/appending-to-array.html), but basically, [`Array#push`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) adds elements to the end of the array, as many as you specify as arguments (e.g., `a.push(1, 2, 3)` pushes `1`, `2`, and `3` onto the array), and [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) calls the function specifying what to use as `this` (the first argument) and the arguments to pass to it, as an array (the second argument).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar. Join two objects but made sure both groupby field had same name, `san`. I needed to append `score` from `some_scores`. Need _.each to create outer join. Map creates final object with name/value you need:

```
   var x = _.chain(moves)
            .union(some_scores)    
            .groupBy('san')
            .each(function(o){ o.push({score:''}); })
            .map(function(o){return {san:o[0].san, to:o[0].to, score:o[1].score  }; })
            .value();
```